# Rendering in Rails (ruby 2.2.1, rails 4.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web

My problem is in rendering error messages, when **@post.save** returns **false**. I don't want use flash messages.

I have two resourses:
**config/routes.rb**

```
  resources :users
  resources :posts, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

User can have many microposts on his personal page (e.g. users/1). And I need to add ability of creating microposts from user's **show view**. Creating with valid information works well, but I want to display **error messages** from **model Post** in another way.

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
...
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      #?????
      render ???
    end
  end
```

**app/views/users/show**

```
...
<%= form_for(@post) do |form| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: form.object %>
  <%= form.text_area :text, placeholder: "Что у Вас нового?" %>

  <%= form.submit "Добавить" %>
<% end %>
```

In partial I am using **object.errors.full_messages**. Any ideas?

Comment: `render partial: 'shared/error_messages'`...... in the `else` part...

Comment: I have to render users_controller's show action. And i have variable in my shared/error_mesages partial...

Comment: have you tried this in controller `render 'users/show', object: @post`

Comment: I have a variable @user in users show view but don't have parameters for it and so get NoMethodError in Posts#create error